# Integral of rational function, could I use efficient way?

Tags: calculus, integration, rational-functions

I have the integral $$\int \frac{x^3+1}{x^3-5x^2+6x}dx$$ I chose to solve it in the following way : first split it for sum of two fractions and decrease the degree of the polynomial of the numerator.
 $$\int \frac{x^3+1}{x^3-5x^2+6x}\,dx=  \int \frac{x^3}{x^3-5x^2+6x}\,dx +\int \frac{+1}{x^3-5x^2+6x}\,dx  $$
\begin{align}
\int \frac{x^3}{x^3-5x^2+6x}&\,dx=\int \frac{x^3+5x^2 -5x^2+6x -6x}{x^3-5x^2+6x}\,dx \\
 =  x + {}&\int \frac{5x^2-6x}{x^3-5x^2+6x}\,dx = x + \int \frac{5x-6}{x^2-5x+6}\,dx\\ = x +{} &\int \frac{-4}{x-2}\,dx +\int \frac{9}{x-3}\,dx =  x -4\ln|x-2| + 9\ln|x-3|
\end{align}

the second integral I solved in similar way and after sum them both I got the answer $$x+ \frac{1}{6}\ln|x| - \frac{9}{2}\ln|x-2| + \frac{28}{3}\ln|x-3| + c $$
wich is correct answer. **But my question is if I could solve it in much shortest and efficient way? could I use long polynomial long dividing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to split $x^3+1$ at the beginning. Performing long division you get that
$$
\frac{x^3+1}{x^3-5x^2+6x}=1+\frac{5x^2-6x+1}{x^3-5x^2+6x}
$$
Then write the denominator as $x(x-2)(x-3)$ and you can rewrite the fraction
as
$$
\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x-2}+\frac{C}{x-3}=\frac{5x^2-6x+1}{x^3-5x^2+6x}
$$
and you get a system in $A,B,C$ by comparing the coefficients.
$$
A+B+C=5 \\
-5A-3B-2C=-6\\
6A=1
$$

So, after you found $A,B,C$, the solution is given by
$$
x+A \ln|x|+B \ln |x-2|+C\ln|x-3|+c
$$

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but can show me the procces of long division of polynomial of the same degree? I am trying to do that but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Well, you divide $x^3$ by the leading term of $x^3-5x^2+6x$ which is $x^3$ and you get $1$. Then multiplying $1$ by $x^3-5x^2+6x$ and subtracting it from $x^3+1$ you get $(x^3+1)-1 \cdot (x^3-5x^2+6x)=5x^2-6x+1$. Now, since the leading term of the remainder has smaller degree than $x^3$ you conclude your division. Thus, the quotient is $1$ and the remainder is $5x^2-6x+1$.

Answer (score 2):

*Much* shorter, I don't know. But the standard way consists in obtaining first the decomposition into partial fractions, which is valid for *proper* rational fractions i.e. fractions $\dfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ s.t. $\deg P<\deg Q$.

- When it is not the case, we first perform the Euclidean divieion of $P(x)$ by $Q(x)$, which is trivial here:
  $$\frac{x^3+1}{x^3-5x^2+6x}=\frac{(x^3-5x^2+6x)+5x^2-6x+1}{x^3-5x^2+6x}=x+\frac{5x^2-6x+1}{x^3-5x^2+6x}$$
- Next we write the denominator as a product of irreducible factors:
  $$x^3-5x^2+6x=x(x-2)(x-3).$$
- So we have a decomposition of the proper rational fraction
  $$\frac{5x^2-6x+1}{x^3-5x^2+6x}=\frac Ax+\frac B{x-2}+\frac C{x-3}$$
  As the roots are *simple roots*, there is a formula for the coefficients: denoting in a generic way the numerator and denominator as $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$, we have
  $$A=\frac{P(0)}{Q'(0)}=\frac16,\qquad B=\frac{P(2)}{Q'(2)}=-\frac 92,\qquad C=\frac{P(3)}{Q'(3)}=\frac{28}3.$$

Comment: I didn't know the formula for the coefficients when you have simple roots, thanks!

Comment: Actually, it works for simple roots, even if there are also multiple roots.